# Is there any way to do multiple "Read More" buttons in Jinja2? If not, how to do it

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

Is there any way to do multiple "Read More" buttons in Jinja2? If not, how to do it?

Example of my code

```
{% for text in somedata %}
    <p>
        {{ text }}
    </p>
{% enfor %}
```

I want to show my page with "Read more" buttons, and when i press it, it shows text and "Read less" button

### Example:

### |Name         |      Info              |

| Mars           |      Read More  |

Comment: Do you need a page with multiple posts with a "Read more" button under each of them? Is `text` variable such post?

Comment: no, i have a table with data.